# Date and Time functions in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, time

I have date and time stored in my database as MySQL `DATETIME` datatype. While inserting into the database, I am using the following PHP variable

`$serverTime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);`

A sample DATETIME stored in database is: `2011-11-26 01:00:27`

Now my website needs the date to be displayed in the following format: `November 26, 2011` (time is not required)

How can I do it? I am trying the below in PHP but wrong output I am getting.

`echo strftime("%B %d, %Y",$serverTime)`

Comment: So many duplicates in the "related" column. Also, what exactly is wrong about the output you are getting? The format looks okay so far

Comment: @Pekka: I am getting `January 01, 1970` output...no matter what the `$serverTime` variable is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would recommend a completely SQL approach, you can use PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class to process your string in PHP (assuming you're running PHP > 5.3):

```
// Pick a valid TimeZone
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', '2011-11-26 01:00:27', new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York'));
echo $date_obj->format('F d, Y');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3vNuYv)

Answer (score 5):

The PHP strftime() function wants input to be a 32-bit integer timestamp, which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

The default output format for MySQL datetime is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.  When you use this string in PHP, the leading digits are converted into the integer 2011, which is interpreted to be within the first hour of 1970-01-01.

So you must fetch the datetime from MySQL in another format.  Choices:

- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_column)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to fetch the datetime as an integer that you can give to PHP's strftime() function.
- [DATE_FORMAT('datetime_column', '%M %d, %Y')](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format the datetime as a string, and then you don't have to use strftime() to format it.

Comment: Another option would be to parse the date format that the db returns with to strtotime() function :)

Comment: I don't count that as an option.  :-)  I try to avoid parsing string representations of numeric data when I can, and this is a case where it's easy to avoid that.